# How to open "Save as" dialog to save a ppt file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a button and on a click of it, I'm calling "get" REST-API call where I get a base64 string.
I'm converting it to blob data and generating ppt out of it by calling it's MIME type.
Issue is, I have to open native "Save as" dialog to chose a file path and name before downloading it.
Kindly help me out how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by this:

```
<a href="data:application/xml;charset=utf-8,Your Data" download="filename.ppt">Save</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't open "save as" file dialog but will directly download it. How can I open the dialog before it is downloaded. Appreciate your help

Comment: for that, you have to go to your browser setting, and then enable "Ask where to save each file before downloading", because some people prefer browser not ask and directly download the file for them, some prefer to choose name and location.